# Display entire list upon entering a jQuery autocomplete textbox

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete). Is there a way that when a user enters a textbox (that is wired up to have autocomplete) the list appears with the top alphabetical items? Some sort of trigger?

***jQuery Code***

```
$('.someTextbox').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: serviceUrl + "/AddDocumentLinesService.svc/GetLineTypes",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false, 
            data: {
                maxRows: 10,
                textStartsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.LineTypeCode + ' - (' + item.Description + ')',
                        value: item.LineTypeCode
                    }
                }));
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I would like it so that the second the user enters the '$('.someTextbox')' textbox the list appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 $('.someTextbox').focus(function() { $(this).search(); });
```

According to the documentation, .search() triggers the search manually. You can also set `options.minChars` to 0 and the `options.delay` to something small, which should also work. See: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions

Comment: this was almost correct. I had tried .search() and it was failing. I then realized I was using the jQuery UI implementation of it since the autocomplete plugin was migrated into the jQuery.UI project. So there was one minor change that can be found here http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-search   $(this).autocomplete("search", " ");

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try setting the `minChars` [option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) to 0, and have `GetLineTypes` check for the length of the given string. if it's 0-length- return first alphabetical items.

another option is to wire to the focus event of the textbox and to trigger the autocomplete functionality manually. maybe you can 'trick' the autocomplete with something like this:

```
$('.sometextbox').focus(function() {
   if ($('.sometextbox').val().length ==0) { 
   //no text entered yet
   $('.sometextbox').val('  '); //insert 2 white spaces in order to trigger the autocomplete
}
});
```

Comment: you're option would work, but @Gijs option was cleaner and found the exact method I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: you're too kind; @Gijs's solution is MUCH better. but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are right.I'm adding this since minChars is deprecated in newer versions.
Use minLength.
Set 
`minLength : 0` 
Also you might consider using a button next to the textfield which kind of acts like a drop down and toggle for all available options.
Happy Coding!

**Edit**
Also since you are loading the whole list, you can make delay as 0,overriding existing behavior of delay which you might have mentioned.

```
$('input#textboxid').autocomplete('search','','delay',0);
```